# Working with dedupper in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a dedupper of phone numbers using php, I have a file with one column of millions of phone numbers in a csv format parsing it in php, my question is, is this the right approach of doing this? I tried with one table, but as the table gets bigger, the slower it handles the searching. Then, I tried this with create table if not exist, separating them using the first 3 numbers.. still the program stops executing at aroung 100k.. any inputs will be so much appreciated.. I have no where else to add features or edit this.

```
if(isset($_POST['upsubmit']))
{
    $dup = 0;
    $forchecknum = 0;
    $inserted = 0;
    $notvalidnum = 0;
    $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; 

    $handle = fopen($file, "r"); 

    while(($fileop = fgetcsv($handle,1000, ",")) !== false) 
    {
            $fileorp[0] = str_replace('.', '', $fileop[0]);

            if(strlen($fileop[0]) == 10){

                $tablenum = substr($fileop[0], 0, 3);               

                if($forchecknum != $tablenum){ //skips create if table is already created
                    mysqli_query($dbc, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `$tablenum` (`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, `phone_number` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, `label_comment` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL)"); //query check if table exist, if not, create one                    
                    $forchecknum = $tablenum;

                    $checkdup = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT `phone_number` FROM `$tablenum` WHERE phone_number='$fileop[0]' LIMIT 1");       
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($checkdup) > 0){
                        $dup++;
                    } else {

                    mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT INTO `tmp_unique_numbers` (`id`, `phone_number`, `label_comment`) VALUES (NULL, '$fileop[0]', 'tmp');");
                    $inserted++;
                    //insert records
                    }

                }else{

                    $checkdup = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT `phone_number` FROM `$tablenum` WHERE phone_number='$fileop[0]' LIMIT 1");       
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($checkdup) > 0){
                        $dup++;
                    } else {

                    mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT INTO `tmp_unique_numbers` (`id`, `phone_number`, `label_comment`) VALUES (NULL, '$fileop[0]', 'tmp');");
                    $inserted++;
                    //insert records
                    }                   
                }

            } else {

                    $notvalidnum++;
                    mysqli_query($dbc, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tmp_not_valid_numbers` (`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, `phone_number` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, `label_comment` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL)"); //query check if table exist, if not, create one
                    mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT INTO `tmp_not_valid_numbers` (`id`, `phone_number`, `label_comment`) VALUES (NULL, '$fileop[0]', '');");                 
            }

            fclose($handle);            
        }



}
```

Comment: Use one table, use prepared statements, set the number column unique. Then the sql server will cache the query, and you wont have to select to check if the number is there as an insert will fail if not unique

Comment: Thank you for the input, wish I could accept your answer, I am new here.. Thank you again.